# Visual Studio, Database project not connected to database

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, database-project

I have a database project and I can't figure out how to connect to the database. My problem is that I can't execute any select statement, store procedure etc... from visual studio. I get messages such as : the object doesn't exist in database, the store procedure could not be found etc. But I'm sure they exist. Sometimes the project is connected to the DB so I can do these operations without problem but sometimes it isn't, today I would like to stop relying on hazard ; ) Until now I was just switching to SQL Management studio whenever this was happening. I am using VS 2013.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer : there is a connection string used for debug that is defined in the project properties. So my problem was actually that whenever I executed queries, VS used this connection string that was actually pointing to localdb.

The fix is simple and consists in going to [Database Project Name] Properties -> Debug Tab and there set the "Target Connection String" to the database you want to query.

When creating a new sql files we are actually prompted to choose the DB we want to connect at the time we execute it. This is why I was thinking that sometimes it worked and sometimes not. But looking back to it, I think that actually it never worked when I was trying to debug existing files.

Hope this helps someone else.